# Размер tabControl

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день.

Хочется узнать, есть ли какой-нибудь способ изменить размер стороны tabcontrol в запущенном проекте при помощи мыши? Хотя бы пример или направление, в котором необходимо изучать.

Answer (score 1):

splitter прикрепить к нужной стороне tabcontrol